# Como fazer uma chamada AJAX através do post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Olá tenho um campo no site chamado buscar atendimento, e gostaria de fazer uma chamada ajax para redirecionar para outra página.

```
  <li>
        <form class="navbar-form full-width">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar Atendimento..." />
                <button id="Busca"  type="submit" class="btn btn-search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </li>
```

Função:

```
  function FiltrarRelatorio() {

        var Busca = $('#Busca').val();

        if (remover === true) {
            Busca = 0;
        }


        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
             url: '@Url.Action("Agendamentos")',
            data: {
                Busca: Busca
            },
            success: function (data) {
                window.location.href = data;
            },
            error: function () {


            },
            complete: function () {

                //location.reload();

            }


        });
    }
```

O que estou fazendo de errado? Quando clico no botão ele apenas recarrega a página de origem ao invés de ir para página de destino.

Comment: De onde vem essa variável `remover` em `if (remover === true) {` e por que a variável `Busca` tem que ser igual a `0`? Onde vc está chamando a função `FiltrarRelatorio()` para executar o Ajax?

Comment: Pq vc está pegando o valor do botão em `$('#Busca').val()`? Não deveria pegar o valor do input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em nenhum momento você está chamando a função `FiltrarRelatorio` e está apenas submetendo o formulário para a própria página, fazendo ela recarregar.

O que você tem que fazer é cancelar o submit do formulário e chamar a função `FiltrarRelatorio`, e pegar o valor do input e não do botão. Coloque a id `#Busca` no input, e não no botão e faça o seguinte:

```
// captura o submit do formulário e chama  a função
$("form").submit(FiltrarRelatorio);

function FiltrarRelatorio(event) {
   event.preventDefault(); // cancela o submit

   var Busca = $('#Busca').val();

   $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: '@Url.Action("Agendamentos")',
      data: {
         Busca: Busca
      },
      success: function (data) {
         window.location.href = data;
      },
      error: function () {
      },
      complete: function () {

         //location.reload();

      }
   });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tiago, você está recuperando o valor do botão ao invés do valor do seu campo.
Defina um id no seu input, por exemplo:

E aí substitua na sua função:
var Buscar = $(“#txtBuscar”).val();